# Simple way to use delta time to make movement smooth

Tags: java

This is a novice question about using delta time to move a sprite across the screen.

Also, I'm looking for advice as to whether or not delta time is even needed in this case...

Here is how I'm calculating delta time:

```
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (lastTime == 0) {
                lastTime = currentTime;
                deltaTime = 0;
            } else {
                deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;
                lastTime = currentTime;
            }
```

And I wanted to use this to somehow make a more fluid movement for objects in 2d space.

This is my current method to move an object up:

```
public void move() {
    this.mPos.y -= mSpeed;
}
```

The thread constantly calls the move() method and it works well but the objects are slightly jittery across the screen. Any tips on how to incorporate delta time into this move() method? I'm trying to set a maximum speed of 10.

Answer (score 2):

The position shouldn't move by the velocity -- the units aren't even the same! If you want to get a position out of a velocity, you need to multiply it by something with units of time (such as your `deltaTime`).

I imagine that your `deltaTime` is going to be quite small, so this should smooth the movement as well since the sprite will be moving more slowly. You'll probably need a higher velocity (or smaller position range) than what you're currently using though. If multiplying your velocity by `deltaType` doesn't get the results you want, I'd try adding a scaling factor and adjusting it around to see the difference it makes.

Comment: Yes, I understand that velocity does not make sense in this situation, it was merely a way to get some movement. I'm more concerned with how I would use a value stored in a long to scale a quantity so that it makes the animation run more smoothly.

Comment: Say you have a scaling factor `long velocityScale`. I would make your velocity scaled by that number in the change to position. Something like `mPos.y += velocityScale * mVelocity * deltaTime`. Note I switched to addition because to me it makes a bit more sense to have your velocity and position aligned, but that's up to you. Try playing with `velocityScale` to see what the results are. I imagine that values less than 1 will help the jitter that you're seeing. What is your `deltaTime` typically? That can get too high if you're doing too many things between time intervals and cause jitter too.

Comment: OK, I will play around a bit. Here are a few deltaTime values that I just captured (separated by commas): 1480054902301, 1480054902347, 1480054902390. Also, when you say you switched to addition is this because of the "up" movement? The object is starting at the bottom of the screen and so to get where it needs to go the y value must be brought closer to 0 from a positive number.

Comment: Those probably make sense for `currentTime` or `lastTime` though, in which case your normal time between steps is ~50ms. That's a bit high if it's tied to the frame rendering and you may see some stutter from that if it is tied to frame rendering. But focus on scaling by `deltaTime` as well since the jitter you're seeing can definitely be caused by time between steps being different and not taking that into account. And I'd make sure that the values you were looking at weren't `deltaTime`. If those were `deltaTime`, you need to look at how you're calculating it.

Comment: Do note that tying frame rendering and physics calculations together is a bad thing with real-world rendering as it causes results of physics to be dependent on your frame rate. But if you're a beginner student, this isn't that huge of a deal at the moment.